# Storing results

Tags: java, data-structures, store

I am doing some assignment using Java and this is what I am supposed to do.
Given an integer `X`, you should read `X` lines, each line containing a string and 2 integer values `x` and `y`.

```
**Input**
2 <-- Read 2 lines
PLUS 10 30 <-- PLUS refers to adding 30 to 10
MINUS -6 20 <-- MINUS refers to minus 20 from -6
**Output**
40 
-26
```

How do I store the value 40 and -26?
I am currently using an array. Code below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    String limitInput = sc.next();
    x = sc.nextInt();
    y = sc.nextInt();
    if(limitInput.equals("PLUS"))
    {
        System.out.println(x+y);
        limitArray[i] = x + y;
    }
    else if(limitInput.equals("MINUS"))
    {
        limitArray[i] = x - y;
    }
    else
    {
        limitArray[i] = x * y;
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler approach like without the use of array?

Comment: You could use a switch, but I would write what is the simplest and clearest to you. You could comment on why only x+y is printed and why the default operator is multiplication.

Comment: Note that using switch on strings is only in `SE 7`

Comment: How about the storing of the data?
Is it possible to store the data without using an array?
I was thinking of storing the data into an integer but that integer value will be overwritten in the loop. =/

Comment: If you know how many lines you're processing in advance, why not use an array? That's what they're built for: situations where you need a list of things that has a pre-determined length. If you really want to get away from arrays, then I guess you could use an ArrayList.

Comment: Hmm... Are there simpler ways to store data other than using data structures like Array, ArrayList, Vectors etc..?

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you prematurely optimizing?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is data structure simpler than array for your case. If you want to store result along with operation /line number; will suggest you to use HashMap. **But ya; map is definitely not simpler than array.**

```
 Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
 int line = 1; //read line number
 int result= 40;  //read final result
 map.put(line, result);
```

This way you can get result for each line by iterating map.

But if you also want to store the operation which you have performed; then will suggest to use multimap like this

```
 Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
 ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 a.add("PLUS"); //add operation
 a.add(result); //add result

 map.put(line, a);
```

When reading value from list; just make sure to parse the value( at position 1) to int as its stored as String.